# Enable HTML tag support using aptana eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, html, aptana

I just installed Aptana 3 eclipse plugin onto Eclipse Helios SR2. WHen I edit a html file using Aptana HTML editor, html5 tag are not recognized. But with a standalone Aptana Studio 3, all the tag are recognized.
Is there a way for me to configure the aptana plugin? I need to use Eclipse for GWT/Google App Engine development.
Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Window -> Preferences, under General select Editors and then file association, change the default editor for html and htm to HTML Editor, note that there are two html editors with the same name. Set the second one as default and create a new html page.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have WST installed with in your eclipse? If so, it might take over the *.html extension and open those files in its editor.

Right click your HTML file and select Open With. If you are using the Aptana HTML editor, you should see there the "HTML Editor" selected (it has a blue tag icon <>).
In case you have WST as well, you might see there multiple options for HTML editor selection.

Also, check that everything is set well at the Preferences under 'File Association'. Check that the 'HTML Editor' is selected as 'Default' when you click the *.html.

Hope that helps

Comment: i had to install WST first before I could install aptana plugin, and I did open html file in Aptana HTML editor, but new html5 tags are indicated as invalid tags.

Comment: It almost sounds like you are using Studio 2. Can you verify the version through the Help -> About menu?